# Радиокнопки с горизонтальной полосой

Tags: html, css, jquery

Не понимаю как в данном примере реализовать длинную серую полосу [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```css
.fl{
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circle1{
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.circle1:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -15px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="fl">
  <div class="circle1">
    заявка
  </div>
   <div class="circle1">
    косультация
  </div>
   <div class="circle1">
    коммерческое предложение
  </div>
   <div class="circle1">
    договор
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а теперь что бы было похоже на тех задание делаем так: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/VwwBOLy

Comment: Понял, в мелочах уже разберусь сам. Спасибо!

Comment: @user358669 Если я Вам помог примите ответ ...